# How does django knows what the password is in create_user() function

Tags: python, django, django-users

I am following [django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUserManager) on creating a custom user model and I am confused in defining the `create_user()` and `create_superuser()`. When defining `create_user()` the password arg passed is `None`

```
def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
    # create user here
    ...
```

While creating `create_superuser()` the password is provided by the caller.

```
def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
    # create user here
    ...
```

How does django knows what the password in `create_user()` function? I am sorry if this is a noob question but I really need to understand. Could you please help me understand the concept here. Thank you.

Comment: I think it's an example for a custom user manager. As such, create_user does not require a password: `The prototype of create_user() should accept the username field, plus all required fields as arguments.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `password=None` in `create_user` method definition means that `None` is default value for password, but it could still be provided by caller.

When you don't provide password for new user or you pass `None` for password Django will create user with unusable password, that means, user won't be able to log in with username and password.

It's useful in scenarios where you want enforce other means of authentication like OAuth or OpenID etc.

Relevant parts of code with comments:

- Implementation of [create_user](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L151)
- [set_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L96)
- Check the `UNUSABLE_PASSWORD_PREFIX` in method [make_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58)

Why for `create_superuser` password is required? Actually it's not. You can always pass `None` as password, but imho it's because you want special rights and privileges for superuser and you are not creating superusers as often as regular users.